# Using Dataprep to write to just a date partition in a date partitioned table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm using a BigQuery view to fetch yesterday's data from a BigQuery table and then trying to write into a date partitioned table using Dataprep.

My first issue was that Dataprep would not correctly pick up `DATE` type columns, but converting them to `TIMESTAMP` works (thanks Elliot).

However, when using Dataprep and setting an output BigQuery table you only have 3 options for: `Append`, `Truncate` or `Drop` existing table. If the table is date partitioned and you use `Truncate` it will remove all existing data, not just data in that partition.

Is there another way to do this that I should be using? My alternative is using Dataprep to overwrite a table and then using Cloud Composer to run some SQL pushing this data into a date partitioned table. Ideally, I'd want to do this just with Dataprep but that doesn't seem possible right now.

BigQuery table schema:

[image]

Partition details:

[image]

The data I'm ingesting is simple. In one flow:

```
+------------+--------+
|    date    |  name  |
+------------+--------+
| 2018-08-08 | Josh1  |
| 2018-08-08 | Josh2  |
+------------+--------+
```

In the other flow:

```
+------------+--------+
|    date    |  name  |
+------------+--------+
| 2018-08-09 | Josh1  |
| 2018-08-09 | Josh2  |
+------------|--------+
```

It overwrites the data in both cases.

Comment: From [BigQuery Data Type Conversions](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/BigQuery-Data-Type-Conversions_102563896#publishwrite), you can use Dataprep's "Datetime (timestamp)" type to write to a `TIMESTAMP` in the BigQuery table, right? I don't think there is a way to use `DATE`, though.

Comment: Thanks for the info @ElliottBrossard. I've managed to get it working using `TIMESTAMP` instead but another problem has arised. Edited the question. Is there a feature request thread somewhere?

Comment: You could submit a feature request to the [Cloud Dataprep issue tanker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=190822&template=0).

Comment: I have the same question! did you manage to do it in DataPrep?

Comment: If you're writing to a single partition, can you use the partition as the destination table, e.g., "table$20180101"? Then Truncate will just remove that partition.

Comment: Hi HuaZhang: unable to select partition. The destination table textbox is uneditable, you have to select it from the GUI. Ideally, I would want to schedule this dataprep job so that it imports the latest date of data and not hardcode a partition. I believe this is likely the wrong use case for Dataprep. @MT467, I ended up just writing the query in SQL and scheduling with Composer

Answer (score 0):

You ca create a partitioned [table bases on DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#partitioned_tables). Data written to a partitioned table is automatically delivered to the appropriate partition.

> Data written to a partitioned table is automatically delivered to the appropriate partition based on the date value (expressed in UTC) in the partitioning column.

Append the data to have the new data added to the partitions.

You can create the table using the bq command:

```
bq mk --table --expiration [INTEGER1] --schema [SCHEMA] --time_partitioning_field date
```

time_partitioning_field is what defines which field you will be using for the partitions.

Comment: How do you write to that partition with Dataprep?

Comment: Data written to a partitioned table is automatically delivered to the appropriate partition

Comment: you just need to send the data to the partitioned table without having to "specify" a partition.

Comment: Is there any way to truncate that partition with Dataprep? As far as I'm aware, you can only truncate the entire table and not just that particular partition

Comment: I understand better, you want to overwrite the data in a partition several times a day, correct me if I am wrong. If this is the case, you can load the data in a temporary table which you can use to WRITE_TRUNCATE using a partition decorator https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#using_a_load_job